# Good NOD units against GDI infantry units in Command & Conquer: Tiberian Sun Firestorm expansion

Tags: command-and-conquer-tiberian-sun

I just got a copy Command & Conquer: The First Decade and started playing the Command & Conquer: Tiberian Sun Firestorm expansion.

I always start off with Tick Tank but they are somewhat weak against GDI Disc Thrower. What are some of the recommended NOD units that is good against GDI infantries?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best anti-personnel units of NOD in early game are Buggy and Cyborg. Wounded Cyborgs heals in tiberium. Using of Light Infantry against Disc Throwers is dangerous because of splash damage of their discs.

Btw, you can crush Disc Throwers by running them over (Tick Tanks and other heavy vehicles can do this).

Answer (score 1):

When it comes to anti-infantry... Nod does have a *flame tank*, you know ;)